# How to add UITableView to existing view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

How do I add a UITableView to an existing view?

I have added the control via interface builder, and added the correct delegates to the host view controller (including adding the table cell functions to the .m file)

But nothing gets called and nothing gets populated, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, for example, never gets called.

**in .h file**

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *friendsScoresView;
```

**in .m file**

```
init {
    _friendsScoresView.delegate = self;
    _friendsScoresView.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // return number of rows
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyBasicCell"];
    //NSMutableArray *nearbyScores = gclb->nearbyScores;

    GCLeaderboardScore *playerScore = [gclb->nearbyScores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",playerScore->score ];
    cell.imageView.image = playerScore->photo;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // handle table view selection
}
```

What am I missing? Also how do I tell the table to update / refresh its contents?

Comment: Did you set the datasource too ?

To update the content, just write [tableView reloadData]

Comment: See my update.. I believe i did..?

Comment: You did ! Are you sure the tableview (the one you added in IB) is linked to your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added the `UITableViewController` in IB then click on the outlets tab on the right and connect the DataSource and Delegate in IB. If you want to do it in code, then create an `IBOutlet` variable for your table and set the delegate and datasource property on your variable. Also, you can't do it on `init` on the `UIViewController` as the NIB has not yet been loaded. Do it on `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for answering.  I setup an `IBOutlet` then set the datasource and delegate in code as above - ill update my question in a moment to show the `IBOutlet`

Comment: Great thanks, just a quick addition - I load the data for the table asyncronously and apparently returning nil for a table cell doesnt work - how do I show nothing until my data has loaded?

Comment: Call [_friendsScoresView reloadData] once you have loaded the data. In this case I like to hide the UITableView until the data has loaded then unhide it after calling reloadData. I put a placeholder image behind the table until it is loaded and appears. Or you can use an Activity Indicator over the table.

Comment: Oh, and return 0 for numberOfRowsInSection until data is loaded. Then it won't ask for a cell.